# Loading special characters in a string loaded via XML in AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

When I load an XML using ActionScript all the characters inside strings render fine except special characters like:

```
ñ, Ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú
```

In that cases the letter is omitted.

I even try with:

```
&ntilde; or &iacute;
```

But in that case show exactly &ntilde; and &iacute; instead of ñ or í.

¿What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to put that string in a text field? What if you do a trace() on the string -- can you see the correct characters there?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your file is UTF encoded and then **embed those additional characters in your `TextField`**. Also, make sure the font you are using supports those characters. While you're at it, wrap your text values in `<![CDATA[]]>` (character data) in the XML file, e.g.

```
<textNode><![CDATA[ñ, Ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú]]></textNode>
```

Comment: Hi, I Try but nothing, I embed all the characters and the trace works fine. Do you have any tutorial or example of a working fine code to compare?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to the embed settings of the textfield and select "Latin I" as the character embedding options. you can also just paste the characters you want to embed in the "additional characters" field. Try also pasting the characters into a textfield with that font to make sure they actually show up.

Answer (score 1):

Save the xml file in UNICODE format.
No need for CDATA.